# Seperate a long html page into smaller 'chunks' with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to jquery, and I want to know if I can use it to turn a long html text into shorter 'chunks', like pages of an ebook. Every time the user press a 'next' button, the next 'chunk' of text is load out on the screen.

If such thing is possible with jquery, what should I read up to code it?

Here is an illustration, hope it will make things easier to understand: http://postimg.org/image/hiydc2ggn/

Comment: yes it is possible. if the page is that large you'll want to read up on AJAX, jquery is especially handy for this. `html()`, `append()`, `appendTo()`, `empty()` and `remove()` are a few jquery methods you can use to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load a portion of an page. You may have to create separate HTML tags though, so you can target their selector. You might consider loading it all at the same time and just use CSS, making sure you have the `overflow:hidden;` and use [.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/). Personally, I would break up your HTML Server Side and use AJAX to get the portions you seek.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the style of a div for the sections set to `display:none` on each section, when the button is pressed you can use something like:

```
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#section2").css({'display':'block'});
    });
```

This is obviously just for one extra section, but you can extend it pretty easily for multiple.